# Sending audio to Lex without using AWSLexVoiceButton (AWS sdk for iOS)

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-lex, aws-lex

I've been trying to use AWSLexVoiceButton for a while but I really dislike how little customization is possible. Is there a way I can send audio to Lex in Swift without using AWSLexVoiceButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the only way to do it is copying over the (objective c) source code and editing it to accomplish what you want.